# window.location.href = "#"; is not working under ajax success section

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Thank you so much to all of your contribution here...

Actually i am facing a problem no any error so please look at this code everything is fine 
but still it's not working..
alert(); is working but window.location.href="#"; not working only in success area.

```
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "newregistration.aspx/newReg",
                data: a,
                datatype: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var s = data.d;
                    if (s == '1') {
                        alert('you have registered successfully');
                        window.location.assign = "http://localhost:6971/registration/registrations.aspx";

                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Sorry can not save try again');
                    }
                },
                error: function ()
                { console.log('Chech you User Id & Mobile No.'); }
            });
```

Notification is showing in IE and Chrome:
Chrome:- Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts a shadow root is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more details.
init @ chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js:465

IE=HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
newregistration.aspx
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. 
For more     information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

Have tried something but still issue is there...

Comment: `window.location.assign` is a function used like this `window.location.assign('url')`, you are trying to assign value to it. Use `window.location.href = 'url';`

Comment: I have tried this because it's not method but window.location.assign also not redirecting on another page.